# MSP430: Need help setting up this TimerA

Tags: c, embedded, msp430, microprocessors

```
#include "project.h"
#include "led.h"

#include "timer.h"

#define DIVIDER 8
#define TMRC (DCO_FREQ / DIVIDER / 1000 * TIMER_INTERVAL)

static tWord tickCount=0;

void Timer_Init() {

    BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_16MHZ;
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_16MHZ;
    BCSCTL2 = 0x0 ; // MCLK clock source DCOCLK, MCLK divider 1, SMCLK source DCOCLK, SMCLK divider 1

    // Set up interrupts and timer 0

    // Enable interrupts on timer
    CCTL0 = CCIE;

    // Use clock SMCLK, UP counting, divided of 8
    TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + ID_3;

    // Set compare value
    CCR0 = TMRC;
}

__attribute__((interrupt(TIMER0_A0_VECTOR))) void Timer_A(void) { 
timer_run(); 
} 

tWord getTick() {return tickCount;}

timer_run() {
   tickCount++;
   Led_Update();
}
```

This code was given for our instructor, I would not like to use it to set up this TimerA to blink the LED at intervals, changeable through the constructor of `LED_Init()` which is ran before this `Timer_Init()`. `TIMER_INTERVAL` will be set before the execution of the Timer_Init through Led_Init().

`DCO_FREQ` is not set anywhere so I am not quite sure what I am suppose to set it to.

I also don't understand the purpose of the tick counter. 
It is also not impossible that the TMRC calculation formula is wrong because logically the TMRC decreases if the preset `TIMER_INTERVAL` is higher, which makes no sense, or does it?

Anyway, somehow I would like it to be able to run at slower intervals, ex 1s or slower, but no Idea how.

Unit: MSP430G2553

Comment: Entering 'MSP430 DCO_FREQ' into a popular search engine gives 'About 20,800 results', with several first-page links that explain the Digitally Controlled Oscillator.   You are probably missing an environment-specific inlcude that sets/defines 'DCO_FREQ'.

Comment: 20,800? I have 350 ish... And I have googled it but not gotten a good understanding of it. If you would direct me to a result that would explain what it is, and what DCO I am running at, I would be more than happy. Also, I have included the header files with all the definitions available for my msp430 version. No idea what even could be missing, and since this code was given by the lecturer one would think he would have put the include there if required,,,

Answer (score -1):

```
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_16MHZ;
DCOCTL = CALDCO_16MHZ;
```

The DCO runs at 16 MHz.

```
#define TMRC (... * TIMER_INTERVAL)
```

> the TMRC decreases if the preset TIMER_INTERVAL is higher

TMRC increases proportionally with TIMER_INTERVAL.